# Remove application from Location Services in Security & Privacy on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: macos, osx-lion, system-preferences

I'm trying to test the installation of an application which uses Location Services (Core Location) on Mac OS X 10.7.

At the moment, it never prompts me for permission to grant the application access to Location Services, because that bundle ID has already been granted permission in the past.

If I untick the box, it assumes I want to disable the application completely, and doesn't ask me again.

How do I remove an item from the Location Services to force it to ask me again?

Comment: Here is the OS X 10.8 / Mountain Lion equivalent:
http://superuser.com/questions/526183/remove-applications-from-location-services-in-security-privacy-on-mac-os-x-10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open a root shell in Terminal, and go to `/var/folders/zz/`. Run `ls -l` and enter the directory owned by `_locationd`.

Open the `C` subdirectory, and run the following command to convert the preferences file from binary to XML:

```
plutil -convert xml1 clients.plist
```

Now edit the file e.g. in `vim` from the command line, removing the application (both `key` and `dict` afterwards) you no longer want to have appear on the list.

Save, and `killall locationd` to have it reload from the settings file.

---

Chances are, that the `PromptedSettings` key is useful as well, if no authorization is given, but I leave figuring this out to the reader.

Comment: This seems to have got my current app into a bit of a pickle. Now it throws a long stack trace when initializing Core Location, even though [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] returns YES. Is there another location where this might be cached?

Comment: Ignore my last comment, this was an unrelated bug with sandboxing.

Comment: @tomtaylor Sandboxing *is* the bug.

Comment: @tomtaylor: I'm having exactly the same problem with sandboxing. How did you work around it?

Comment: @sudorm-rf: Apple confirmed it's a bug in 10.7.4, fixed in 10.8. Hopefully patched in 10.7.5 too, but I've not checked.

Comment: @tomtaylor: I submitted a radar about it and it was marked as dupe. I was about to use one of my support incidents on it. Would you say that would be a waste?

Comment: Thanks for this, saved me tearing my hair out with messed up preferences. I've also found that it's sometimes necessary to manually edit an entry's `Authorized` key to enable/disable it. The checkboxes don't seem to stick always.

Comment: What do you mean by "killall locationd" ? When I write it in Terminal, I get : "No matching processes belonging to you were found". Thanks.

Comment: I removed the key relative to my app from the dictionary but now I have some bugs... 1) I have got a discrepency between the clients.plist file and what is displayed in my preferences: I no longer have my app in the plist (I removed it) but it is still displayed in the preferences 2) Even if I clicked on the alert to allow the location services, the key is not back to my clients.plist 3) My app is no longer able to determine my location even if [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]  always returns YES => always get didFailWithError

Comment: 4) If I allow or forbid the location services for my app in the user preferences, the result is the same: the location is not determined. Anybody can help me ? By the way, what do you mean with this sandboxing bug ?

Comment: Actually, the behaviour of all these stuffs became completely cahotic... 1) Sometimes I get the startup alert, sometimes not 2) the list of apps using location services sometimes displays all my apps using location services, sometimes is empty... 3) In all cases, the clients.plist is never modified ! Any idea ?

Comment: @Regis_AG Are you really on OS X 10.7, for which both the question and answer were written?

Comment: I am on OSX 10.7.5. Thanks for your support... It is a nightmare !

Comment: @Regis_AG I'm using OS X 10.8 so I cannot investigate -- maybe it's named `_locationd` on your system as on 10.8? Run `ps aux | grep location` and see what the result is. Kill it.

Comment: I am going to try what you are saying. Actuallt I am wondering if the problem is not due to the fact that I could not access the "C" folder and I executed the following command : sudo chown -R my_name: "c" Can this change in the permissions have an influence ? If yes, what can I type to repair my mistake ? Thanks!

Comment: @Regis_AG You started out wrong -- read the first four words of my answer again. Then you can `chown _locationd`, that's an internal system user.

Comment: Thanks for your help Daniel, I really appreciate. I understand that I would not have had to change the rights if I ran Terminal in root mode with sudo -s ; correct? Here is the result of ps aux | grep location (I really don't know what this means :)): "myname      2036   0,0  0,0  2425480    200 s000  R+    6:52     0:00.00 grep location" What do you conclude about this? What should I do? What do you mean by "kill it" ? What do you mean by "Then you can chown _locationd"? Sorry but I am a newbie with Terminal... Thanks again!!

Comment: @Regis_AG This just means that the location service on your system is not currently running. Chances are, your permission change broke it. Revert that, restart the system, try again.

Comment: I restarted my system once more and still not works. Does "myname 2036 0,0 0,0 2425480 200 s000 R+ 6:52 0:00.00 grep location" mean that the location service of my system doesn't work ? It is indeed the feeling I have got ! Here are the permissions of the "C" folder: "drwx------  10 myname _locationd  340 21 déc 17:01 c" Do you see anything wrong? Thanks!!!

Comment: Here is the permission on the "C" folder on backup of my disk: "drwxr-xr-x  5 myname  staff  170 20 sep 23:58" ('ls -ld c' command) It seems that some permissions are lacking on the folder on my computer (previous post)... Tell me what you think about that. Thanks again.

Comment: @Regis_AG Again, just `chown -R _locationd C` to revert what you broke earlier, and it should work again.

Comment: Thaaannnnnkssss !!!!!!!!!!!! It works again !!!! YOU ARE A GENIUS !! :) What I did (for those who could have the same the same problem as me: 1) sudo -s (to be in Terminal root mode) 2) chown -R _locationd C 3) Restart my computer And it works ! For my culture, what does 'chown -R _locationd C' do ? How did you know that I had to type that ? If you come to Paris, I will pay you (at least) a pint of beer ! I really thought that my Mac was broken :( Thanks !!!

Comment: (ChangeOwner -Recursive Username Directory)   it recursively changed the ownership of all directories and files including C, to be owned by user _locationd